# Как проверить тип dynamic аргумента?

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно выполнять проверку на тип - содержащийся в dynamic?

Т.е что то типа:

```
static dynamic Method(dynamic argument)
{
    if(argument.GetType()==Int32)
    {
        //Выполняем тело метода
    }
    else 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

(Просто оно ругается на Int32)

Comment: *А что, операторы `is` или `typeof` у вас кто-то отобрал?*

Comment: `typeof(Int32)`.

Comment: @Grundy: `is` же?

Comment: @VladD, в его пример typeof :) Бамкни молотком

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, так там GetType вовсе не нужен

Comment: @Grundy: Я с телефона :-/

Answer (score 3):

```
static dynamic Method(dynamic argument)
{
    if(argument is Int32)
    {
        //Выполняем тело метода
    }
    else 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```